# ExpandableListFragment doesn't exist. how to deal with it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

The titles are not my forte so I will try to put this as clear as possible.

We have a `ListFragment` and now we have to convert it to smth like an `ExpandableListFragment`, which doesnT exist apparently.

Obviously, there are gists and individual attempts ([this](https://github.com/domoritz/open-mensa-android/blob/master/src/android/support/v4/app/ExpandableListFragment.java), [this](https://gist.github.com/bowmanb/4052030) and [this](https://github.com/robotmedia/robocommons/blob/master/RoboCommonsLibrary/src/net/robotmedia/widget/ExpandableListFragment.java))

but I wonder why Google itself didnT offer this solution in the first place. Because, [ExpandableListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html) per se, is available.

1. Any guesses why?
2. How do I go about creating an Expandable ListView in Fragment? 
   Should I take down my existing `ListViewFragment` and try using an `ExpandableListView` in a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1):

1. They might found that useful, as there are multiple situations where you need to display a list with values. Maybe the fragment version is on his way :)
2. Implement your own `Fragment` and add the `ExpandableListView` there.